# How can I send information to a document from the url?

Tags: javascript, html

I am unsure how to word this question so editing is greatly appreciated - edit before you downvote!
How can I do something like Google has done:

> https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?tab=ww&ei=d7hPU4L4IMOl0wWqzICICA&ved=0CBYQ1S4#q=stackoverflow

They have a question mark ('?') and then a variable which is set by the previous page.
How does this work and what do I need to do to utilize it in my page, and with javascript?
Please edit this if you know how to word it better.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
window.location.search
// "?tab=ww&ei=d7hPU4L4IMOl0wWqzICICA&ved=0CBYQ1S4"
window.location.hash
// "#q=stackoverflow"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

PHP:

```
$_GET["tab"]
// ww
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Hash values are not sent to the server and thus are not available in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I wanted!